# Display all categories in Multi select dropdown jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, multi-select

This is my code for multi select dropdown

```
<select class="form-control" id="lstFruits" required multiple="multiple" name="catId[]">
    @foreach($catlists as $category)
    <option value="{!! $category->id !!}"    >{!! $category->name !!}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#lstFruits').multiselect({
            includeSelectAllOption: true
        });
        $('#btnSelected').click(function () {
            var selected = $("#lstFruits option:selected");
            var message = "";
            selected.each(function () {
                message += $(this).text() + " " + $(this).val() + "\n";
            });
            alert(message);
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Question:**

When I select more than 4 categories it displays 4 selected, but I want to display these 4 categories in a dropdown.

It display this:

[image]

I want something like this, all categories should be displayed.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#configuration-options-buttonText), you have to override the `buttonText` property:

```
$('#lstFruits').multiselect({
    ...
    buttonText: function(options, select) {
        var labels = [];
        options.each(function() {
            if ($(this).attr('label') !== undefined) {
                labels.push($(this).attr('label'));
            }else {
                labels.push($(this).html());
            }
        });
        return labels.join(', ') + '';
    }
});
```